# Show Woo Commerce Price Variation Before Product Short Description

Tags: woocommerce

i want to show Show Woo Commerce Price Variation Before Product Short Description

our website made in wordpress and we use **woodmart theme** and for product price variation We use this plugin:
**Ni WooCommerce Product Variations Table
**
**i want to show the product price table like this in below given image means Show WooCommerce Price Variation Before Product Short Description
**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBKl6.png)

i want to show Show Woo Commerce Price Variation Before Product Short Description

i expact change the in this givwen image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwNpg.png)

Answer (score 0):

I havent tested it but try the following. Place the code in your functions.php

```
// Remove the action from its original hook
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', array( 'Ni_wooCommerce_After_Single_Product_Summary', 'ni_woocommerce_after_single_product_summary' ) );

// Add the action to the desired hook with the specified priority
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', array( 'Ni_wooCommerce_After_Single_Product_Summary', 'ni_woocommerce_after_single_product_summary' ), 55 );
```

Answer (score 0):

They have the Layouts builder which can help you to customize the product page in the way you want. Check this article: https://xtemos.com/docs-topic/woodmart-woocommerce-layout-builder/